# select columns from a file with awk having a threshold but print the user defined column?

Tags: awk, grep

I want to select first 4 columns from the below file with a threshold value less than in the 6th column

```
chr start   end copy number status  WilcoxonRankSumTestPvalue   KolmogorovSmirnovPvalue
1   761750  7202499 3   gain    5.13822497072701e-298   0
1   7289250 7289999 7   gain    0.014309298726355   0.0366367750948455
2   98611750    98612249    6   gain    0.0332886037857768  0.270077169105485
2   113816500   114398999   3   gain    3.96934332204917e-17    5.55111512312578e-15
2   121103500   122122749   3   gain    1.00740734942511e-17    4.25659507641285e-13
2   128322500   128471749   3   gain    7.89316303630306e-28    0
2   218620500   219303499   3   gain    0.00830885602834e-56    0
2   220084750   220085249   6   gain    0.0232886037857768  0.270077169105485
2   220085250   220506749   3   gain    5.22993652708892e-114   0
```

The file contains 7 columns. I want to select first 4 columns without the header but only those columns which has values in 6th column less than equal to 0.05.

I have work out the columns I need and also do away with the header but how will I use the threshold on column 6 but not use it in printing. I would print only `$1,$2,$3,$4` which have `$6` column values less than equal to 0.05.

Is it possible to do this with a single `awk` command with a pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate it into:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $6<0.05 {NF=4; print}' file
```

Which returns:

```
1 761750 7202499 3
1 7289250 7289999 7
2 98611750 98612249 6
2 113816500 114398999 3
2 121103500 122122749 3
2 128322500 128471749 3
2 218620500 219303499 3
2 220084750 220085249 6
2 220085250 220506749 3
```

This fetches all lines from the 2nd line in case its 6th value is lower than `0.05`. If so, it removes the extra columns by setting `NF` (number of fields) to `4`. Then, it prints the line.

Note you can pretify it piping to `column -t` like this (thanks Glenn in comments!):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $6<0.05 {NF=4; print}' file | column -t
1  761750     7202499    3
1  7289250    7289999    7
2  98611750   98612249   6
2  113816500  114398999  3
2  121103500  122122749  3
2  128322500  128471749  3
2  218620500  219303499  3
2  220084750  220085249  6
2  220085250  220506749  3
```

Comment: This also works for me. I have made the command.  `awk -v OFS='\t' '{if($6 <= 0.05)print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file.txt | grep -v "start" | head` . This will only give first 4 columns which will have values in the 6th column less than equal to 0.05 so in this case only 4 rows should be output

Comment: it is a bit complicated to know how your output should look like. Could you cross check what you mean with column and what with row? Providing your desired output would make it.

Comment: The output should be only the first 4 columns with values whose 6th column are less than 0.05. Try my command it works.

Comment: @fedorqui, he just wants `NF=4` and `$6 <= 0.05`, and maybe pipe into `column -t` to prettify

Comment: exactly so the command which @fedorqui should be modified `awk 'NR>1 && $6<0.05 {NF=4; print}' file` . This gives the output am looking for

Comment: @vchris_ngs ooook so I just updated to match what you were asking for

Comment: Thanks a lot @ fedorqui

Comment: You are welcome, @vchris_ngs ! Remember you can always accept an answer if your issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui. Sorry I did not accept it as answer. If you see even the command I wrote in one of the comments also works and gives the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to select the first four columns for $6<=0.05

```
awk '{if($6<=0.05){print $1,$2,$3,$4}}' file
```

Output

```
1 761750 7202499 3
1 7289250 7289999 7
2 98611750 98612249 6
2 113816500 114398999 3
2 121103500 122122749 3
2 128322500 128471749 3
2 218620500 219303499 3
2 220084750 220085249 6
2 220085250 220506749 3
```

Comment: Yes even this command works well except I am also introducing tab delimeters as I need to save it in a different format of file. If you see the command I have used then you will see the output.